# Run a method and update progressbar using tpl

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void timeConsumingCode(){
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

and then i have my Form1 code:

```
private void btn_RunTimeConsumingCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task loadMasterFile = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
        myClass.timeConsumingCode();
    });
}
```

till now everything works fine. However I added a progressbar on the form and I want to update it based on the value of `i` ie. if `i=34` then 34% done.

I could `invoke` the progress bar property from the `timeConsumingCode()` to change the value but i want to keep the class as separate as possible from the form so that in the future it can be ported to other apps.

Is there a way that I can change the value of my progressbar without having to make the `MyClass` depended on the form1?

I hope I was clear enough

Comment: If this is WinForms, the `BackgroundWorker` class is excellent for this type of notify scenario:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TPL in the .net 4.5 framework has an [`IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) interface that is implemented as [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx). In your case, as you'll need a single number as a progress report you could use a `Progress<int>` instance and attach an event handler to its `ProgressChanged` event, along these lines:

```
private void btn_RunTimeConsumingCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(p => {...ui handling code ...});

    Task loadMasterFile = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
      MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
      myClass.timeConsumingCode(progress);
    });
}
```

coupled with calling

```
progress.Report(someNumber);
```

at the appropriate places in the `MyClass.timeConsumingCode` method.

Of course, the event handler (here specified as a constructor argument) is called asynchronously.

Comment: There's a nice document about the Task Asynchronous Pattern [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) that goes in detail about this.

Comment: @SWeko this is definitely the direction i want to go in! However I'm confused as to how would I code the ...ui handling code ... in other words, how would I set the maxvalue and the new value for the progress bar?